# How to routing to concern throug controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To have a cleaner code I want to split my controller in some concerns.

In my routes.rb how to redirect to concern without redefine the methods of concern `index show destroy create ...`

```
class SomeController
  include SomeConcern

  def index
  end
end

module SomeConcern
  def index
  end
end
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: A concern is just a module that is included in classes. You don't route to concerns - you route to controller classes. I don't know if the question is unclear or if you just don't understand how module mixins are used.

Comment: Thanks is clear, i must create a sub controller to do what i want ?

Comment: I have no idea what you want. Concerns are a tool to share functionality between different classes such as controllers. You cannot route to a module (a concern is a module) since it is not a class and cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say we have a `CarsController` and `AirplanesController` that have the typical `create` and `new` actions.

```
class AirplanesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @airplane = Airplane.new
  end

  def create
    @airplane = Airplane.new(create_params)
    if @airplane.save 
      redirect_to @airplane
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
  # ...
end

class CarsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @car = Car.new
  end

  def create
    @car = Car.new(create_params)
    if @car.save 
      redirect_to @car
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

To dry this up we can extract the shared code to a module:

```
module Createable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessor :resource
    alias_attribute :self.controller_name.to_sym, :resource
  end

  def new
    @resource = resource_class.new
    yield @resource if block_given?
  end

  def create
    @resource = resource_class.new(create_params)

    if @resource.save 
      yield @resource if block_given?
      redirect_to @resource
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def create_params
    raise "not implemented controller!"
  end

  def resource_class
    @resource_class ||= self.controller_name.classify.constantize
  end
end
```

We can then apply it to the controller classes by:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  include Createable

  def create_params
    params.require(:car)
          .permit(:model) # ...
  end
end

class AirplanesController < ApplicationController
  include Createable

  def create_params
    params.require(:airplane)
          .permit(:model) # ...
  end
end
```

But a very important point here is that you are not routing to the module. The module is providing methods to the controller class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to always map to your controller. Concerns are modules where you can put shared logic (it makes sense only in case you need 2 absolutely similar methods in 2 different controllers).

I think, that such code should work:

```
class SomeController
  include SomeConcern
end

module SomeConcern
  def index
  end
end
```

Isn't it?

But concerns mostly used to move out some private helper methods from controller, rather actions as we do in this code piece